# What document file format; uses ascii characters only, preserves page layout, and opens in MS word?

Tags: ms-word, formatting, tags, ascii, document

I am writing a python app that will edit and output a text file. I want the text file to be similar in function to a well formatted html page. I thought odt files were plain text with formatting tags but a text editor will not open it.(it is compressed) I tried saving as fodt (flat odt) but MS word refuses to display it properly. rtf seems to work a bit but the formatting is severely distorted in MS word.

I thought there was a simple plain text formatting language that preserves layout and opens correctly in ms word. PostScript comes to mind but I don't think msword will edit .ps files.

Am I dreaming this??

Many thnaks for any hepl.

--Molly J.

Comment: There is IMO *one* single-file format that can represent most, if not all, of a modern Word document and that is the so-called flat-OPC .xml format. It's like the .docx format, which is really a Zip file format, but flattened into a single text file. Great if you want to **save** a .docx file in a single file format, but **creating** one from scratch is non-trivial because for example, the representation of paragraph styles is opaque. The older rtf format can't represent everything in a modern Word document and isn't all that easy to generate (unless you save it from Word!)